# Implementing account scoping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Currently in my application I have the concepts of projects and users. Now I'm wanting to implement an account scope for these so that both projects and users belong to an account rather than to nothing in particular. By doing this, I would like to scope my routes like this:

```
 scope ":account_id" do
   resources :projects
   ...
 end
```

However, by implementing a routing `scope` with a named parameter this changes how the routing helpers perform so that the `project_path` routing helper now expects two parameters, one for the `account_id` parameter and one for the `id` parameter, making it something like this:

```
  project_path(current_account, project)
```

This *tiny* `scope` change requires me to make *massive* changes across the application in the controllers and views where I use these path helpers.

Surely, surely, surely, there's a clean way to do this without having to change every single routing helper in the application?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the default_url_options hash to add a default value for :account_id:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :set_default_account_id

  def set_default_account_id
    self.default_url_options[:account_id] = current_account
  end
end
```

You can then use the url helper with a single parameter:

```
project_path(project)
```

You can override it in a view by passing :account_id as a hash parameter to a route:

```
project_path(project, :account_id => other_account)
```

Note that this won't work in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Since Rails 3.0, manipulating url params is even simpler with [url_options](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/url_options):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  def url_options
    { account_id: current_account.id  }.merge(super)
  end
end
```